# How to use loop(any) to put the output of the equation in same equation and get new value for particular set of values in python?

Tags: python, loops, equation

I want to use equation `{Xn=2.6*X*(1-X)}` put the initial value of X as 0.4 and get 1st Xn and use it as X in the same equation and like this get the first 50 values.

This is what I tried:

```
x=float(input("enter the initial guess:"))
xn=2.6*x*(1-x)
print(xn)
for x in xn:
    print(xn)
```

And

```
count=0
print(2.6*x*(1-x))
while x>=0.4:
    count+=x
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `for` loop

```
x = 0.4
for i in range(50):
    x = 2.6 * x * (1 - x)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of that makes sense unless you assume Python can do prolog-style symbolic evaluation, which it cannot.

Python is not a complicated language: you have expressions, which are evaluated, and bound to variable. It looks like what you want here is to [iterate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) on your equation: apply it to an initial value, then re-apply it to its own result.

AFAIK Python has neither `iterate` nor `unfold` as part of its standard library, but you can easily enough create a *generator* for a specific instance of iterating:

```py
def the_thing(x=0.4):
    while True:
        # swap if you don't want the initial value to be returned
        yield x
        x = 2.6 * x * (1-x)
```

You can then iterate on a section of this:

```py
for x in itertools.islice(the_thing(), 50):
    print(x)
```